# tableview not refreshing by using notificationcentre and tableview.reloaddata()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

here is the code I use to refresh a tableview when I click a delete button on my custom tableview cell by using notificationcenter and tableview.reloaddata(). I have searched a bunch of other codes and i think my code looks fine. I don't know why it just doesn't refresh.

This is where my tableview is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    username = tempUser.username
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller

    })()
    get{(value) in
        self.values = value
        for ele in self.values{
            if self.username != ele["username"] as! String{
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(serviceBoard.methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent), name:"NotificationIdentifie‌​r", object: nil)

}

func methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(){
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return values.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!postCell
    let maindata = values[values.count-1-indexPath.row]

    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {


        //            if (filteredTableData[indexPath.row].rangeOfString("###") == nil){
        cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        cell.title.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.category.text = "SERVICES"
        var price = String()
        for i in values{
            if (i["title"] as? String)! == filteredTableData[indexPath.row]{
                price = (i["price"] as? String)!
                cell.categories = "Services"
                cell.username = i["username"] as! String
                cell.prices = i["price"] as! String
                cell.notes = i["notes"] as! String
                cell.school = i["school"] as! String
            }
        }
        cell.price.text = price 

        return cell
    }
    else {
        if maindata["username"] as! String != username && username != "admin"{
            cell.deleteBtn.hidden = true
        }
        else{
            cell.categories = "Services"
            cell.username = maindata["username"] as! String
            cell.prices = maindata["price"] as! String
            cell.notes = maindata["notes"] as! String
            cell.school = maindata["school"] as! String
        }

        cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        cell.title.text = maindata["title"] as? String
        cell.category.text = "SERVICES"
        cell.price.text = maindata["price"] as? String

        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPostT") as! showPostT
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        for i in values{
            if (i["title"] as? String)! == filteredTableData[indexPath.row]{
                popOverVC.type.text = "SERVICE"
                popOverVC.typeImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
                popOverVC.item.text = "Service: \(i["title"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.price.text = "Price: \(i["price"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.notes.text = "Notes: \(i["notes"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.comments.text = i["comments"] as? String
                popOverVC.postUser.text = i["username"] as! String
                popOverVC.notesStr = i["notes"] as! String
                popOverVC.category = "service"
                popOverVC.pricesStr = i["price"] as! String
                if username == popOverVC.postUser.text!{
                    popOverVC.composeBtn.hidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        let maindata = values[values.count-1-indexPath.row]
        popOverVC.type.text = "SERVICE"
        popOverVC.typeImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        popOverVC.item.text = "Service: \(maindata["title"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.price.text = "Price: \(maindata["price"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.notes.text = "Notes: \(maindata["notes"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.comments.text = maindata["comments"] as? String
        popOverVC.postUser.text = maindata["username"] as! String
        popOverVC.notesStr = maindata["notes"] as! String
        popOverVC.category = "service"
        popOverVC.pricesStr = maindata["price"] as! String

        if username == popOverVC.postUser.text!{
            popOverVC.composeBtn.hidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my custom tableview cell

```
class postCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
var prices = String()
var notes = String()
var comments = String()
var locations = String()
var categories = String()
var school = String()
var username = String()
var date = String()


@IBAction func deleteAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.percyteng.com/orbit/deletePost.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "name=\(username)&location=\(locations)&price=\(prices)&notes=\(notes)&school=\(school)&category=\(categories)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume();           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifie‌​r", object: nil)


}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated:animated)
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried this, self.tableview.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(UITableView.reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: false)

Comment: I will try it out when I get home!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not updating the `values` property when you click on the "Delete" button.

```
func methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(){
    // you have to update the `values` array so that it doesn't contain the value you've just removed.
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: so should I grab data from databse again in this method? Haha I have been thinking that tableview.reloadData() will do all the work automatically. And those other answers never mentioned this! I will try it out!

Comment: You can send the object that you removed inside the `userInfo` when you post the notification. But for this you will need to have a reference for it in the cell.

Comment: I am confused about what you said here. U meant after/when I post the notification, I can send the whole cell to my main class that contains the tablewview? Can I not just get data again in methodhandlingTheNotification() and reload tableview?

Comment: You can definitely get the data again :) Just in case you have lots of data, in order not to reload it you may send the deleted object together with the notification and then just remove it from the `values` array. Both solutions will work, it's just a matter of performance.

Comment: Sounds good! I think that's the reason why my tableview.reloaddata() isn't working. It's really helpful. I don't get to access my code right now. I will accept this answer after I test it out later! :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload table in viewDidAppear().

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your data source before reloading `tableview` then only your tableview will affected otherwise you will always got old table.

I think `maindata` is main datasource in your `cellforrowAtIndexpath`. So you have to update or delete from your datasource and then you should reload data.

Comment: That sounds right, so the solution i think is to reload the data from database in methodhandlingTheNotification(), but you sound like I need to do something in cellforrowAtIndexPath. How would I be able to refer to that method from methodhandlingTheNotification() and change the tableview, maindata is just a local variable inside of cellforrowatindexpath